# iOS apps closes right after launch

Tags: ios, xcode

I created and install several iOS apps using Xcode , it worked fine , but in a few days I tried to launch some of them. I tried to launch an app, It showed launch screen and closed immediately after launch screen . I launched Xcode and reinstalled that app, it worked fine. But in a few days problem appeared again.

P.s. When I tap home button twice, I can see information  of crashed(closed) app, that information have to appear after launch screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a paid developer account, do you?

If you have the free developer account, the certificate will stay valid only seven days. That's why you have to reinstall you apps every 7 days on your devices.

Comment: I don't have a paid developer account.  I inspected that in my profile in "management profiles" tab of "preferences" there were some signed apps, only those apps worked. Thank you very much.